# post data - ngResource AngularJS

Tags: web-services, angularjs, http-post, ngresource

Hello !

I develop a RESTful webapp with AngularJS, I use the `ngResource` module to send http requests. The webservice is developped with FuelPHP.

I'm having a problem to creating a resource with the `$save` method of `ngResource`. My web service doesn't receive post data.

When I check the http request with Firebug, I can see the post data.

I don't understand why the post data are not received by the webservice. So if you have an idea, it would be cool to help me.

Sorry for my bad level in English.

Here is the code :

```
Service : 
app.factory('Medication', ['$resource', 'global', function ($resource, global) {
    return $resource(global.API+'/medication/medication', {}, {})
}])
```

---

```
Method in the controller : 
$scope.addMedication = function() {
    var newMed = new Medication();
    newMed.name = 'nameValue';
    newMed.increaseinr = 1;
    newMed.details = 'detailsValue';
    newMed.$save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with how PHP is handling the POST.  When using AngularJS $resource it will POST the object with JSON as the post's BODY.  PHP does not see this as a regular parameter.  I've had to do this in other PHP (never used Fuel)

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestBody = json_decode($requestBody, true);
```

Then you should be able to inspect $requestBody as a normal json object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to config the $save method with a request method of 'POST'

Comment: I think that the default type of the save method is POST.
Anyway, I tried it and it doesn't works.

    app.factory('Medication', ['$resource', 'global', function ($resource, global) {
     return $resource(global.API+'/medication/medication', 
      {}, 
      { "save": {method:"POST"} }
     )
    }])

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
Indeed, data is post in the request's body. 
With FuelPHP, I used Input::json('key') to get the values (and not Input:post('key'))

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default option 'transformRequest' of $http to change the transfer formation of the post data.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');  

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){  
        if (data === undefined) {  
            return data;  
        }  
        return $.param(data);  
    }  
});
```