# Angularjs post request using $resource API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-services

I am a starter in angularjs , am trying to do a log in form ,when user submits the form i am connection to a REST API url

```
http://XXX/XXX/index.php/report/login/format/json
```

when configuiring the url in PostMan rest client it works fine.!

But while configuring this url in angularjs as shown below and registering as a service

```
 User = $resource('http://xxx/xxx/index.php/report/login/format/json',{},
 {
   query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
   create: { method: 'POST' }
  });
User.create({email: user.email,password: user.password});
```

also tried enabling **CORS** in server side of no use.

i get a 404 error and values are not posted.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
AngularJS put the post's data in the body of the request. Sometimes, the server can't find these post datas. For example, data didn't appear in the $_POST[] variable.
That's why it works with Postman. To verify what is really sent in your request, I advise you to use Chrome tools.
My solution was to change the getting of data on the webservice.

Here is the topic : [post data - ngResource AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438917/post-data-ngresource-angularjs)

Comment: By looking at his resource I don't see why angular should put stuff in the body. The attributes from the first object passed to `create` should end up in the request URI as query parameters (`.../format/json/?email=...`), and not in the body.

Comment: When you make a POST request, parameters doesn't appear in the URI. Parameters appear in the URI just when you make a GET request. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Right, I was forgetting it is a POST and not a GET.