# AngularJS $http Service Results in Success But Database Doesn't Get Updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS, and I'm trying to perform an http service to send data to a php file for input into MySQL. I have been able to get this to work using jQuery and the `$.ajax` function so I am sure my PHP is alright.

My ultimate question: Is the way that I am implementing this AngularJS service correct? I have binded an `ng-click` to a function on an `a` element called `routeReloader(data)`. When I `console.log` the parameters within the routeReloader function, I get the correct parameter. I am also getting an alert box of "success." However, it isn't updating MySQL.

```
userApp.controller('photoController',  ['$scope','$location','$log','$route','$http',    function($scope,$location,$log,$route,$http){

    $scope.routeReloader = function(parameters){
        $http.post('centralcommand.php', {id: parameters}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            alert('success'); 
        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            alert('failure');
        });
    };

}]);
```

I get the data in the centralcommand.php file using `$_POST['id']`.

**JQuery Working Equivalent**

```
$('#link-element').click(function(){

        var REL = $(this).attr("rel");
        var URL = 'centralcommand.php';
        var dataString = 'id=' + REL;

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: URL,
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success : function() {
            alert('success')
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: Maybe problem in url? Did you tried full url with http prefix?

Comment: I have used the entire localhost URL and it works. If I didn't have the correct URL, the alert would state 'failure'.

Comment: No, when problem in url, alert won't execute, there will be failure inside http service, not in request itself

Comment: The console doesn't output any errors. When you use a wrong URL, it gives a 404 error. I'm not getting that error. I tested with a bad URL to be sure.

Comment: But when url is not correct, it will thrown protocol error, for example when you accidentally use double // slash

Comment: In php file echo $_POST['id'] and write console.log in angular and print data variable and check id passed on or not

Comment: angular post data by json, so php may not get the params. 
[like this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438917/post-data-ngresource-angularjs)

Comment: angular post data by json,  php may not get the params. 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438917/post-data-ngresource-angularjs

Comment: What variable do I use within the PHP file to transfer the JSON. For example: 

$jsonDecoded = json_decode(????);

What should be placed in the question mark area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution based on the comments with the fact that the data getting passed is in JSON format. I had to decode the JSON format into something that PHP could use:

**PHP CODE**

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$photoID = $request->id;
```

Convert JSON format with this PHP code, and you can use it within your SQL queries. Note that `$request->id` uses the same `id` that gets passed in the AngularJS $http post request.